# useRef hook returns null in context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using `useRef` hook in my context. I am logging that out in `useEffect` hook inside context. I passing that `useRef` variable so that it can be accessed my components. Here is the context.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export const SearchContext = createContext({});

export const useSearch = () => useContext(SearchContext);

const SearchProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const loader = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(loader); // returns {current: null}
  }, []);

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider
      value={{
        loader
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SearchProvider;
```

Next in my component I am adding `ref` property to div element with value `loader` which is coming from `context`. However, when I run this code I see `{current: null}` for `loader`. How can I use useRef in context to have access to DOM elements in component to make this work?

Here is my component

```
import { useSearch } from "./context";

const Component = () => {
  const { loader } = useSearch();
  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={loader}>Hello</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Here is the sandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-jepsen-l83mf?file=/src/component.js:0-203

Comment: In the Sandbox link you provided, it is printing the DOM node. Isn't that what you want?